# Issues with creating table via migration

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-south

I have created a model and when I try to create the table via migration using `python manage.py migrate app_name` and in response I get

```
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for app_name.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

But the table is not created , its a simple process but I don't know why the table is not created. The db used is postgresql and I have also used syncdb but doesn't work .

Comment: It says `nothing to migrate` which means it haven't found any migrations. Make sure your `app_name` folder have `migrations` child.

Comment: IT has migrations folder but I have just created a new model and run this command , Is their anything else I have to do before run command in terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you haven't created any migrations. You need to create them, before they can be run.

For app's initial first migration you run:

```
./manage.py schemamigration your_app --initial
```

For following migrations you run (provided you want to create an automatic migration):

```
./manage.py schemamigration your_app --auto
```

You can see more examples [in the tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html).